# rails validation error undefined method 'x' for Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

In my ActiveRecord Payment Model I have:

```
attr_accessible :amount, :client_id, :confirmation_id, :method, :plan_id, :firstname, :lastname, :address1, :city, :state, :zip, :expiremonth, :expireyear, :cardnumber, :cvv2
validates :firstname, presence: true
validates :lastname, presence: true
validates :address1, presence: true
validates :city, presence: true
validates :state, presence: true
validates :zip, presence: true, numericality: true
validates :expiremonth, presence: true
validates :expireyear, presence: true
validates :cardnumber, presence: true, numericality: true
validates :cvv2, presence: true, numericality: true
validates :plan_id, presence: true, numericality: true
```

Most of these are associated attributes through 'belongs_to :client'. Including :state.
However, :cardnumber, and :cvv2 are not... They just must be validated somehow.

In my Payment - Cart View I have:

```
<%= form_for @payment, :url => { action: "checkout" } do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field(:plan_id, :value => @plan.id) %>
<%= f.text_field :firstname, :value => @client.firstname %>
...More form field tags like this....
<%= f.collection_select :state, State.all, :statecode, :state %>
...More form field tags...
<%= f.text_field :cardnumber %>
```

But, the 'f.' does not seem to work for :state, :cardnumber, :cvv2 because I get "undefined method 'state' or 'cardnumber' or 'cvv2' when I try to visit the cart page. If I have the f. there to ensure it gets validated.

**Question 1 = Why am I getting an error on :state? When it is a part of the client model like most of the other fields that work. Am I setting up the collection_select incorrectly?**

**Question 2 = How can I set up the other "virtual" attributes (if that is the correct term) like :cardnumber and :cvv2 to be validated without getting the same error that I am getting for state. (undefined method) **

Comment: You need to have methods for them.

Comment: Have you run your most recent migration(s)?

Comment: All recent migrations have been ran.

Comment: What about question 2?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you need to make a nested form since :state isn't an attribute of @payment but rather of @client. The reason your earlier fields are working is because you define the value of of them to be @client.attribute rather than simply :attribute. For all the client attributes I would do

```
f.fields_for :client do |ff|
```

Comment: This does work for the attributes that need to be populated from the client data.

Comment: This is a separate question but do you know how to allow the model to validate these? For instance now I have `<%= f.fields_for @client do |ff| %> <%= ff.text_field :zip %>` and I get this from the form if I blank out that field "payment"=>{"client"=>{"zip"=>""... but.. of course `validates :zip, presence: true, numericality: true` won't validate this.

Comment: why dont you validate them in the client model instead? alternatively you could do a callback for payment which says before_save :check_validity_of_client_fields and then define that. i'm not sure about a direct validates method for client attributes in the payment model though. if you want to make sure that those things are just present, in the payment model you could say accepts_nested_attributes_for :client, reject_if: :all_blank (or another reject_if proc - see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: How could I validate them in the client model? I'm not familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my Model:
For VirtualAttributes and it seems to have solved this problem.

```
    attr_accessor :expiremonth, :expireyear, :cardnumber, :cvv2
```

And I'm pulling the the other attributes directly from @client per @ussferox suggestion here in her answer.

However, getting them populated with the proper default data and allowing that data to persist and validate are other issues. But that is for another time.